# Collider in Phaser 3 randomly doesn't work

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework, collider

I just began coding in Phaser 3 after developing some games with p5.js and wanted to make a 2d endless runner game. So here's the code for my game:

```
var game;
var gameOptions = {
    monkeyGravity: 1200,
    monkeyPower: 1000
}

window.onload = function() {
    let gameConfig = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        backgroundColor:0x87ceeb,
        scale: {
            mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
            autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
            parent: 'thegame',
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080
        },
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {debug: true}
        },
        scene: [
            startGame,
            playGame
        ]
    }
    game = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
    window.focus();
}

class startGame extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super('StartGame');
    }
    preload(){
        this.load.image('menu-bg', '/jeffrey2nd/menu-bg.png');
        this.load.image('play-button', '/jeffrey2nd/play-button.png');
    }
    create() {
        this.menuBg = this.add.sprite(game.config.width / 2, 0, 'menu-bg').setScale(2);
        const screenCenterX = this.cameras.main.worldView.x + this.cameras.main.width / 2;
        const screenCenterY = this.cameras.main.worldView.y + this.cameras.main.height / 2;
        const startButton = this.add.sprite(screenCenterX, screenCenterY, 'play-button');
        startButton.setInteractive();
        startButton.on('pointerdown', () => this.scene.start('PlayGame'));
      }
}


class playGame extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super('PlayGame');
    }
    preload(){
        this.load.image('background', '/jeffrey2nd/background.png');
        this.load.image('backgroundL1', '/jeffrey2nd/backgroundL1.png');
        this.load.image('backgroundL2', '/jeffrey2nd/backgroundL2.png');
        this.load.image('backgroundL3', '/jeffrey2nd/backgroundL3.png');
        this.load.image('backgroundL4', '/jeffrey2nd/backgroundL4.png');
        this.load.image('ground', '/jeffrey2nd/ground.png');
        
        //ANIMATIONS
    
        this.load.image('run0',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_000.png');
        this.load.image('run1',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_001.png');
        this.load.image('run2',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_002.png');
        this.load.image('run3',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_003.png');
        this.load.image('run4',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_004.png');
        this.load.image('run5',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_005.png');
        this.load.image('run6',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_006.png');
        this.load.image('run7',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_007.png');
        this.load.image('run8',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_008.png');
        this.load.image('run9',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_009.png');
        this.load.image('run10', '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_010.png');
        this.load.image('run11', '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_011.png');
        this.load.image('run12', '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_012.png');
        this.load.image('run13', '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Running_013.png');

        this.load.image('jump0',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Jumping_000.png');
        this.load.image('jump1',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Jumping_001.png');
        this.load.image('jump2',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Jumping_002.png');
        this.load.image('jump3',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Jumping_003.png');
        this.load.image('jump4',  '/jeffrey2nd/animations/monkey/Jumping_004.png');

    }
    create(){
        
        //BACKGROUND AND LAYERS
        this.bgLs = this.add.group();
        this.background = this.bgLs.create(0, game.config.height / 2, 'background');
        this.backgroundL1 = this.bgLs.create(0, game.config.height / 2, 'backgroundL1');
        this.backgroundL12 = this.bgLs.create(game.config.width, game.config.height / 2, 'backgroundL1');
        this.backgroundL2 = this.bgLs.create(0, game.config.height / 2, 'backgroundL2');
        this.backgroundL22 = this.bgLs.create(game.config.width, game.config.height / 2, 'backgroundL2');
        this.backgroundL3 = this.bgLs.create(0, game.config.height / 2, 'backgroundL3');
        this.backgroundL32 = this.bgLs.create(game.config.width, game.config.height / 2, 'backgroundL3');
        this.backgroundL4 = this.bgLs.create(0, game.config.height / 2, 'backgroundL4');
        this.backgroundL42 = this.bgLs.create(game.config.width, game.config.height / 2, 'backgroundL4');
        
        for (let b of this.bgLs.children.entries) {
            b.setOrigin(0, 0.5);
        }
        
        //GROUND PLATFORMS      
        this.groundGroup = this.physics.add.group();
        this.ground1 = this.groundGroup.create(0, game.config.height - 50, 'ground');
        this.ground2 = this.groundGroup.create(game.config.width, game.config.height - 50, 'ground');
        this.ground3 = this.groundGroup.create(game.config.width + game.config.width / 2, game.config.height - 275, 'ground');
        this.ground4 = this.groundGroup.create(game.config.width + game.config.width / 1.5, game.config.height - 500, 'ground');
        this.ground4.setScale(0.5, 1);
        for (let g of this.groundGroup.children.entries) {
            g.setOrigin(0, 0.5);
            g.setImmovable(true);
            g.setScale(1,0.3);
            g.body.checkCollision.down = false;
        }
        
        //MONKEY
        this.monkey = this.physics.add.sprite(game.config.width / 10 * 2, 500, 'run0');
        this.monkey.setScale(0.3);
        this.anims.create({
            key: "player-run",
            frames: [
                { key: 'run0' },
                { key: 'run1' },
                { key: 'run2' },
                { key: 'run3' },
                { key: 'run4' },
                { key: 'run5' },
                { key: 'run6' },
                { key: 'run7' },
                { key: 'run8' },
                { key: 'run9' },
                { key: 'run10' },
                { key: 'run11' },
                { key: 'run12' },
                { key: 'run13' }
            ],
            frameRate: 20,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key: "player-jump",
            frames: [
                { key: 'jump0' },
                { key: 'jump1' },
                { key: 'jump2' },
                { key: 'jump3' },
                { key: 'jump4' }
            ],
            frameRate: 20,
            repeat: -1
        })
        
        this.monkey.body.setSize(this.monkey.width/2, this.monkey.height/2);    
        this.input.on('pointerdown', this.jump, this);
        this.input.on('pointerup', this.fall, this);
    }
    update(){
        this.backgroundL1.x -= 0.2;
        this.backgroundL12.x -= 0.2;
        this.backgroundL2.x -= 0.4;
        this.backgroundL22.x -= 0.4;
        this.backgroundL3.x -= 0.6;
        this.backgroundL32.x -= 0.6;
        this.backgroundL4.x -= 0.8;
        this.backgroundL42.x -= 0.8;
        
        for (let b of this.bgLs.children.entries) {
            if (b.x <= -game.config.width) b.setX(game.config.width);
        }
        
        var speed = 5;
        
        for (let g of this.groundGroup.children.entries) {
            g.setX(g.x-speed);
            //if (g.x <= -game.config.width) g.setX(game.config.width);
        }
        
        if (this.ground1.x <= -game.config.width) this.ground1.setX(game.config.width);
        if (this.ground2.x <= -game.config.width) this.ground2.setX(game.config.width);

        
        if (this.ground3.x <= -game.config.width) {
            this.rnd1 = (Phaser.Math.Between(0, 500))/100;
            this.ground3.setX(game.config.width + game.config.width / this.rnd1);
        }
        if (this.ground4.x <= -game.config.width) {
            this.rnd2 = (Phaser.Math.Between(0, 500))/100;
            this.ground4.setX(game.config.width + game.config.width / this.rnd2);
        }
        
        this.physics.world.collide(this.groundGroup, this.monkey, ()=> {console.log('touche' + game.loop.time )}, null, this);
        
        this.monkey.body.gravity.y = gameOptions.monkeyGravity;

        if(this.monkey.body.touching.down) this.monkey.anims.play("player-run", true);
        else this.monkey.anims.play("player-jump", true);

    }
    jump(){
        if(this.monkey.body.touching.down) {
            this.monkey.body.setVelocity(0, -gameOptions.monkeyPower);
            this.monkey.anims.stop();
            this.monkey.anims.play("player-jump");
        }
    }
    fall(){
        if (this.monkey.body.velocity.y < 0) this.monkey.body.setVelocity(0, -100);
    }
}
```

Game start scene has the Start Button, the game begins, the monkey runs on the platforms and you can jump on the upper platforms.

All seems to work fine, but sometimes randomly the monkey falls down off the screen.
You can see a playable version of the bug at https://420videogames.com/jeffrey2nd

Here I added a console log in the 'monkey vs ground goup collide' callback function, logging the `game.loop.time` to try to understand. My idea was that maybe some frames were missed during Update and the objects did not collide perfectly, but when the monkey falls off, the callback function runs 2 times and then the monkey keeps falling and the game breaks up.

Another strange thing about this issue is that on my mobile phone REDMI8 the game works with no problems, as for the iPhone8 of my GF. On Firefox mobile of another friend, by the way, the game has the same PC issue.

Thank you in advance for your attention, hope someone can help me fix this problem,
Ab

Comment: I added `this.monkey.setCollideWorldBounds(true);` and the monkey still falls off from the platforms, but doesn't get out from the display screen. May it be a real physic problem?  I mean if the monkey was too heavy and the platforms could not stop it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved moving the colliders from Update function to Create function.